# Loopback generating documentation with Docular not working

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm following the getting started with LoopBack section of the docs (http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Add+a+client+app). They tell you to use this command:

```
lb-ng-doc client/js/lb-services.js
```

To get some browser viewable documentation. All I get when I run that command is:

```
-------- verifying plugins --------
```

as opposed to a bunch of output at the terminal, ending with "Browse the documentation at localhost:3030/", which is what the docs say I should be seeing. Anyone run into this problem?

Answer (score 4):

run this command as "root" or with "sudo"

Answer (score 0):

Did you generate `lb-services.js` properly? Try regenerating it via `lb-ng <path/to/server.js>` and then running `lb-ng-doc lb-services.js` again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows cmd prompt, you may have to run as administrator. Right click cmd.exe and select "Run as administrator".